# pyspark udf with multiple arguments

Tags: python, pyspark, data-science

I am using a python function to calculate distance between two points given the longitude and latitude.

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    newlon = lon2 - lon1
    newlat = lat2 - lat1

    haver_formula = np.sin(newlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(newlon/2.0)**2

    dist = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(haver_formula))
    miles = 3958 * dist 
    return miles
```

My dataframe has 4 columns -  lat, long, merch_lat, merch_long.

When I create a UDF like this, it throws me error. I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
udf_haversine = udf(haversine, FloatType())
data = data.withColumn("distance", udf_haversine("long", "lat", "merch_long","merch_lat"))
```

error is:

```
An error occurred while calling o1499.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
```

How to create a udf that takes multiple columns and returns a single value?

Comment: I think it's valid to pass in multiple columns into your UDF like that. The error message you gave is pretty generic and could happen for a number of reasons. Could you share more details about it?

Comment: https://medium.com/@nikolasbielski/using-a-custom-udf-in-pyspark-to-compute-haversine-distances-d877b77b4b18 might help

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are having problems with `numpy.dtype` and serialization.

Since `miles` is of type `numpy.float64` try returning `float(miles)`.

Full example that works:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
import numpy as np


def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    newlon = lon2 - lon1
    newlat = lat2 - lat1
    haver_formula = (
        np.sin(newlat / 2.0) ** 2
        + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(newlon / 2.0) ** 2
    )
    dist = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(haver_formula))
    miles = 3958 * dist
    return float(miles)


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {
        "long": 18.427238,
        "lat": 19.510083,
        "merch_long": 93.710735,
        "merch_lat": 52.182011,
    }
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
udf_haversine = F.udf(haversine, DoubleType())
df = df.withColumn("distance", udf_haversine("long", "lat", "merch_long", "merch_lat"))
```